# Can we increase the number of choices for close -> offtopic -> migrate to other SE site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When closing questions that are offtopic, you can suggest that they be migrated to another StackExchange site.

The current list of other sites is just Robotics meta.  How many choices can we put here?  I would suggest that at a minimum we put in:

- Electronics
- Raspberry Pi
- Philosophy
- Ros (if it exists)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking only graduated sites get an expended migration target list.

There is precedent for a Beta site to get extra migration targets, but only after a clear need was demonstrated by a large number of existing migrations.

While we occasionally migrate to Electronics or other sites, the number of migrations is very low, so suggestions for migration through flagging are probably the most appropriate way of handling this for now.